# Why the Content Deployer is down after previously running correctly

Tags: deployer

I setup the Content Deployer and it was working well (I got the **'SDL Tridion ASPX Upload'** message all the time), but after trying to solve some issues with the Tridion Website configuration by playing with the IIS settings and AppPool (basically just turning on and off the authentication methods) and installing the sqljdbc classpath, I think I disconnected something.

I put back the settings of the AppPool and IIS and no matter what I do (resetting IIS, recycling the AppPool, creating a new AppPool, selecting different authentication methods), I get the error below.

Remember I haven't done anything to the IIS folder (didn't change either the config files in the bin/config folder.

I also checked that all the Tridion Web Services were on and they are. I also created a test.aspx in a different IIS folder and it worked so IIS is not down.

What can I be missing? Remember, it was working before and I haven't touched the files of the deployer folder, and IIS is working. Also, the Tridion Content Manager is working with no issues whatsoever.

The error below is misleading as before it was showing that it could not load **Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData** and now it says it's can't load **Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice**. Sometimes these errors appear when I change the type of IIS Authentication method but after putting back the original authentication settings still doesn't work.

I know it doesn't necessarily have to do with the Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice, I think it's a misconfiguration somewhere else, but where? Am I missing to check something else?

I appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

****UPDATE***

I deleted unncessesary DLLs in the deployer's bin folder and now I get this error

```
Server Error in '/tridion-deployer' Application.

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
Line 2:  <%
Line 3:      Tridion.ContentDelivery.Transport.HttpUpload.HandleRequest(Request, Response);
Line 4:  %>
Line 5:  

Source File: e:\inetpub\wwwroot\tridion-deployer\HTTPUpload.aspx    Line: 3 

Stack Trace: 


[BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.GetJvmLoader(Int32 ctorVersion, String configFile, String vers, String conf, String reserved, Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, Int32 traceFacility, Int32 traceLevel, Int32& error) +0
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +158
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader() +54
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaStringPinning(String str, Int32 length, IntPtr& result) +67
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NativeInterface.ToJavaString(String str) +78
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add_string(String str) +158
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj, Type type) +243
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethodArguments.Add(Object obj) +49
   Org.Slf4j.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String name) +75
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Utilities.LoggerFactory.GetLogger(String loggerName) +23
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Transport.HttpsReceiver..cctor() +20
```

---

Previous error was:

---

```
**Server Error in '/tridion-deployer' Application.**

***Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.***

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

**Exception Details:** System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

**Source Error:** 

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice' could not be loaded.       

    Stack Trace: 


    [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
```

Comment: Can you confirm the App Pool is set for .Net 4.0?

Comment: Sure it is 4.0. I also followed the article http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tridion-content-delivery-deployment-errors-unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt-and-system-badimageformatexception to no avail yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your error messages it indicates you are loading the incorrect format of DLL. I assume this is 2013 SP1, on the cd-layout we deliver 64bit and 32bit binaries. Most likely you have these two mixed with each other.

It could also be that you changed your application pool to stick to 32bit mode but you still have 64bit libraries. It is some combination of this that you are facing.

Comment: Awesome, I had changed the DefaultAppPool to Enable 32-Bit applications. Changed it back and restarted the AppPool. Thanks.